# ViewModel navigation with TabBarPresenter

Tags: xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller, mvvmcross

I have made a `HomeViewModel` which contains some other `ViewModel`s to be presented in a `TabParPresenter`. This works fine and the `ViewModel`s associated `View`s are presented correctly in their corresponding tabs. However on of the `ViewModel`s have a check in the `ctor` that tells it in when some conditions apply it needs to navigate to `SettingsViewModel` , which is not a part of the `ViewModel`s contained in `HomeViewModel`.
The navigation event gets caught by the `TabBarPresenterHost`, which is simply the `Presenter` of the application and if a `TabBarPresenter` is present and not null it is passed to the `TabBarPresenter.ShowView()` method. All this happens before the `TabBarPresenter` is done loading and `SelectedViewController` is set in `ViewDidLoad`. Hence the `TabBarPresenter` relies on using the `SelectedViewController` to push new `View`s I obviously get a `Null Reference Exception`.

In short what I want is:

```
if (conditionForShowingHome == true)
    GoToHome();
else
    GoToSettings();
```

Then when inside `SettingsViewModel` I have set the stuff I need when going back you return to `HomeViewModel`.

What breaks this is that the `ViewModel`s are loaded before the `View` is done loading and the navigation event is executed before the `View` is done loading. Any ideas how to go around this?

Comment: Maybe I should add that the TabBarController is ripped out of the Cirrious Conference sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that putting this code inside a ViewModel constructor is likely to lead to problems.

The ViewModel constructors are called during navigations - and not all platforms will support starting new navigations while existing ones are still in progress.

To workaround this, I personally opt to put this type of behaviour in the code before the navigation.

- In the case of a normal navigation, this can go inside an MvxCommand execution handler.
- In the case of application startup, I do this in a custom app start - see some notes in https://speakerdeck.com/cirrious/appstart-in-mvvmcross

Comment: I did the custom application startup, which works for me, will have to look into what to do on Android and WP7.